# Проверка наличия изображения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Подскажите, есть ли способ проверки ссылки на изображение через JS?

Например, есть 2 изображения с указанными адресами:

```
<img src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" />
<img src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128d.png" />
```

Первое с правильной ссылкой, а второе - нет. При обнаружении битой ссылки - добавить `.hide()` или класс, значения не имеет. Спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте метод `error()`

```js
$('img').error(function() {
   $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
img {
    border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" />
<img src="https://www.google.ru/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128d.png" />
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.