# Проверка ссылки на изображение. Битая или нет

Tags: jquery

Есть способ проверить `<img>` на наличие битой ссылки на изображение, а есть ли способ проверить **именно** ссылку на изображение?

[Проверка наличия изображения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660887/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: Т.е. проверить, возвращает ли реквест на ссылку статус 200?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вообще все просто, создаем изображение и пытаемся загрузить его. Если получилось - ссылка есть, если не получилось, то вероятнее ссылки нет ( либо проблемы на сервере )

```js
const checkImgSrc = src => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = function () { console.log(`valid src: ${src}`); }
  img.onerror = function () { console.log(`unvalid src: ${src}`); }
  img.src = src;
}


checkImgSrc('eruiqnwg');
// возможно ссылка уже устареет, но все же
checkImgSrc('https://fullhdpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Snow-Leopard-Full-HD-Wallpapers.jpg');
```

Comment: Из всех ответов Ваш оказался рабочим)

Answer (score 4):

**С помощью jQuery**

```
$('#myImage').on('error', function () {
  $(this).attr('src', 'path_to_default_image.png');
});
```

**Нативный JS**

```
var image = document.getElementByID('myImage');
image.onload = function () {
  console.log('Done');
};

image.onerror = function () {
  image.src = 'path_to_default_image.png';
};
```

Comment: Если на момент запуска скрипта img уже был обработан браузером, то ничего из этого не сработает

Answer (score 2):

В JQuery можно проверить ссылку на изображение с помощью функции [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
Единственное условие: URL изображения и URL сайта должны иметь один и тот же протокол (т. е. HTTP только с HTTP, а HTTPS только с HTTPS). По крайней мере, так в Google Chrome. Это сделано для безопасности клиента. Подробнее см. [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Правило_ограничения_домена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) и https://learn.javascript.ru/same-origin-policy.

Код:
https://jsfiddle.net/0cjh96st/95/

```js
$("#check-it").click (function () {
  $("#img-container").append('<p class="wait">Wait...</p>');
  $.ajax($("#url").val())
  .done(function(jqXHR) {
    $("#img-container").append('<img class="ok" src="'+$("#url").val()+'">');
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR) {
    $("#img-container").append('<div><p><span class="wURL">Can\'t open URL: </span>'+$("#url").val()+'</p><p><span class="wURL">status: </span>'+jqXHR.status+'</p></div>');
  })
  .always (function () {
   $(".wait").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
}
#img-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#img-container>* {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #feb;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
}
#img-container>.ok {
  border-color: #bef;
}
.wURL {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #febfeb;
}

#url {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <p class="label">
    URL of image:
  </p>
  <input type="text" id="url">
  <input type="button" id="check-it" value="Check it!">
</div>
<div id="img-container">
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery.ajax() Description: Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ Перевод: выполняет асинхронный HTTP (Ajax) запрос. Согласно документации запрос всегда http.

Comment: @Anamnian `http запрос` никак не привязывает вас к протоколу.