# Показать картинку заглушку, при получении битой ссылки на картинку

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, img

столкнулся с проблемой, получаю ссылку на картинку с бэкэнда. Некоторые ссылки битые, и ничего не показывают. Как заменить битую ссылку на  путь до картинки заглушки, которая лежит у меня в проекте?

Код:

```
<img :src="preview_url" alt="Превью" class="preview">
```

где `preview_url` глобальная переменная, условно: `https://placeimg.com/200/300/cats`. С каждым запросом мы получаем разную ссылку на картинку.

Пробывал так-

`<img :onerror="this.src= '../../assests/myImg.jpg'" :src="preview_url" alt="Превью" class="preview">` 
, не помогло.

***UPD***

Так же пробывал сделать как в это [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863479/303105).
И изменить `preview_url` в событии `onload` и `onerror`. Ноль реакции.

Comment: `<img :onerror="preview_url =  '../../assests/myImg.jpg'" :src="preview_url" alt="Превью" class="preview">` как-то так

Comment: @Дмытрык Есть один нюанс, когда используется оператор `:` пред `src`, картинка до которой указан путь ` '../../assests...'" ` не отображаться

Comment: директива  `:`, указывает на то, что к этому аттрибуту необходимо примениить значение переменной. Если картинка, до которой указан путь, не отображается, то, скорее всего, проблема в пути или в картинке. Посмотрите в итоговом html - что там

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app', 
  data: {
    images: [
      'https://example.com/not-exists-1.jpg', 
      'https://picsum.photos/200/120/?random',
      'https://example.com/not-exists-2.jpg'
    ], 
    img404: 'https://i.imgur.com/st2SrKk_d.jpg?maxwidth=640'
  }
});
```

```css
#app img { height: 120px; margin: 0 0.2rem; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <img
    v-for="(src, i) in images" :key="i" :src="src"
    @error="e => e.target.src = img404"
  >
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

---

Если `src` как в примере, берутся из массива, и его содержимое изменяется в рантайме (например, новые картинки добавляются), то вот такой подход будет лучше:
`@error="images.splice(i, 1, img404)"`

Это заменит сам элемент в массиве, вместо изменения атрибута элемента.

---

При использовании `@error` на кастомных компонентах не выводящих это событие, нужно добавлять модификатор `native`.

Answer (score 2):

Можете сделать так:

```
<template>
  <div>
<img :onerror="imageLoadOnError" :src="preview_url" alt="Превью" class="preview">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import defaultImage from '../../assets/images/no-image.png';
  export default {
   methods: {
     imageLoadOnError(e){
       e.target.src = defaultImage;
     }
   }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, проблема заключается в смене пути к файлу картинки. Получаем в виде: `http://www.picshare.ru/view/10317000/` , если она поломалась, то пытаемся поменять путь на `../../assets/images/no-image.png';`, поэтому она не отражается.

Comment: путь к картинке из кода компонента не совпадает с тем, который в итоге, запрашивает браузер. Укажите путь, исходят из того, как будет запрашивать его браузер и все получится

Answer (score 1):

Я когда-то делал через background-image. То есть если картинка не прогрузилась, то у нее фон, как у, например, `div`а, а если прогрузилась - картинка ее перекрывает.

Ну и нужно `min-width` и `min-height` задать, думаю.